# Using Applescript to scan a volume, pull out the path, file name and a number and output results csv

Tags: applescript

I have been at this for two days.
So, using Automator and Applescript, I need to scan a volume (or volumes) and get a path to each file, the file name plus extension, assetID (if there is one) and output each part to a comma separated csv file.

So far, I have the Automator actions sorted out and most of the Applescript part but I am at my wits end. The paths and file names work but extracting the assetID (if there is one) is the problem. Not every file has an assetID (and those I am not interested in). The assetID is always a 10 digit number at the end of the file preceded by an underscore("_") like so - **afilename_1234567890.ext**. As it is now, the script will display the assetID's of the files it processes but as soon as it gets to a file with no id, I see the following error, "The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: Can’t get text 1 thru -1 of "".” Something is getting munged somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The script so far...

on run {input, parameters}

```
-- save delimiters to restore old settings
set savedDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters

-- set delimiters to delimiter to be used
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"

repeat with aPath in input

    -- set a variable to contain the "/" (POSIX) version of the files path
    set filesPath to POSIX path of aPath

    -- get the file name
    set fileName to last text item of filesPath

    -- get the file name without the extension
    set thePrefix to text 1 thru ((offset of "." in fileName) - 1) of fileName

    -- get the asset ID, if there is one
    set assetID to rightStringFromRight(thePrefix, "_")

    display dialog assetID

    if (class of assetID) is integer then
        -- get the path only
        set pathOnly to ((text items 1 thru -2 of (get POSIX path of aPath)) as Unicode text) & "/"

        -- output the path only, file name and asset ID to a comma delimited csv file


        display dialog assetID
    end if
end repeat

-- restore the old delimiter setting
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to savedDelimiters
```

end run

on rightStringFromRight(str, del)

```
local str, del, oldTIDs

set oldTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters

try
    set str to str as string
    if str does not contain del then return str
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to del
    set str to str's last text item
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTIDs
    return str
on error eMsg number eNum
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTIDs
    error "Can't rightStringFromRight: " & eMsg number eNum
end try
```

end rightStringFromRight

on is_number(number_string)
    try
        set number_string to number_string as number
        return true
    on error
        return false
    end try
end is_number

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the script working. A few wrong assumptions corrected and all is well.